# Can't access to Windows 10 share from a Windows 2000 machine

Tags: windows-10, smb

Recently made a hard decision to upgrade to Windows 10, a trend unstoppable.

After that I reinstalled VirtualBox and import all of my VMs (Win2K+Win7). Found out that Windows 2000 guests can't access my share on the Windows host anymore. After changing LsaCompatibilityLevel to 1, still no use. Meanwhile, the Windows 7 guest can access it without disturbances.

Anymore I can do to solving the issue? Thank you.

Comment: You need to enable NTLM v1. See security level 1 here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/network-security-lan-manager-authentication-level

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960646.aspx - registry info here

Comment: Back from work and had some tests. Sadly it didn't worked, either.

Comment: Followed the [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and), installed SMB1.0 server, restarted the lanmanserver on Win10 host, tried every value 0-5 of lmcompatibilitylevel, still actively refused as 'file not found' error appeared instantly on the Win2K guest.

Comment: WORKS for me, once I enable SMB 1/CIFS support in Windows 10, no issues after that. Would be nice not to have to do that, but it does work. This is with Windows 10 v1809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Win 2000 does not support SMBv2 , and with the Win10 update (disable SMBv1 from Windows 10RS3) All Win OS prev Win 2000 will not access your Win 10.
[link](https://thehackernews.com/2017/06/windows-10-redstone3-smb.html)

Comment: Pwned by Microsoft. Anyway I gave up and use \\Vboxsvr now...